# How to run a Query to extract all fields of a Specifc Table for display name having some words

Tags: mysql

I want to create a query to get all the information from a specific table and must have DisplayName Like '%-DEE%'

Comment: SELECT * FROM  SPECIFICTABLE WHERE DISPLAYNAME LIKE '%DEE%'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Comment: This is pretty fundamental, I have a hard time believing that this question wasn't answered somewhere on the internet before or can't be found on MySql documentation. However if you are really a total novice it's the SELECT statement, though knowing about LIKE%% disqualifies you as a novice :).

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from specifictable
where DisplayName Like "%-DEE%"
```

But please get yourself into SQL before asking basic questions.